# Using \pageref via \label in Referencing a Page

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, labelling

I am writing a simple document using the fancyhdr package for the header and footer and also the hyperref package. I use \label to label a page.

Here is my MWE (**EDITED**):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, paperheight=11.69in, paperwidth=8.27in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Upper Left Header  \\
    Lower Left Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Upper Right Header  \\
    Lower Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{page:2}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{fancier}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{ Header 2  \\ \phantomsection\label{page:2}
Header 3 }
\fancyhead[R]{Header 4  \\
Header 5}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{page:2}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\fancypagestyle{fanciest}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{page:2}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\begin{document}

    \thispagestyle{fancy}

\pagestyle{fanciest}

    This is page 1.

    \newpage

\thispagestyle{fancier}

    \label{page:2}

This is page 2. 

\newpage

This is page 3.

\end{document}
```

When I compile this, it works fine but when I click the page numbers marked with \pageref, it brings me to the first page. How do I fix the code in such a way that the page numbers marked with \pageref, it will bring me to the second page which starts at the headers? I know that the lastpage package can be used to bring me to the last page (third page in this MWE) but I do not want that. Just in case it helps, I am using XeLaTeX since I use PSTricks figures.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can set an anchor: \phantomsection\label{page:2}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you so much for your reply. I have edited the TeX code (see above). I want to link the \pageref to the header in the second page. The code runs but I do not achieve my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\pageref` always links to the last target set by a sectioning command or some other command setting a target like `\phantomsection`. So it it typically jumps somewhere into a page.

To always get a fix position located above the header you can use the page target (pageanchor) that hyperref adds to every page at the top left of every page. But currently there is no good interface to retrieve its name for a link (this will improve with the next hyperref and LaTeX release). As long as you don't use the options `plainpage` or `hypertexnames` (and naturally do not use `pageanchor=false`) you can link to such a target through a label like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[headheight=24pt,left=0.50in, right=0.50in, top=1.00in, bottom=1.00in, paperheight=11.69in, paperwidth=8.27in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{refcount}
\fancypagestyle{fancy}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{Upper Left Header  \\
    Lower Left Header}
\fancyhead[R]{Upper Right Header  \\
    Lower Right Header}
\fancyfoot[L]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pagetargetref{page:2}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\NewDocumentCommand\pagetargetref{m}{%
 \hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{#1}}{\pageref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}

This is page 1.

\newpage

\label{page:2}

This is page 2. 

\newpage

This is page 3.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. That works. However, if I set a newpage to 1 using \setcounter{page}{1}, the pageref brings me to the page that has the new number page "1" on it rather than the original page1 (first page).

Comment: well you shouldn't do that. Every page needs an unique name, both for anchors and to avoid to confuse your readers. If you want two pages with number 1, you should give them different representation, e.g. roman and arabic.

Comment: Yes, it is not that neat but is it possible to do it? Many thanks. ^^